# What is the name of this geometric shape - A Cylinder with a Cone Atop?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I've been unable to find the geometric name for the following shape, does one exist?

[image: A Cylinder with a Cone Atop Its Top]

Comment: I would probably call it "a cylinder with a cone on top."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65405/discussion-on-question-by-james-what-is-the-name-of-this-geometric-shape-a-cyl).

Comment: If the cylinder were considerably longer, laypeople might call it a pencil, but that term is already [used for something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencil_(mathematics)) in geometry.

Comment: Thanks for taking a go at it, MvG.

Answer (score 1):

Can't find anything better than ["Cylindro-conical shape"](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Cylindro-conical_tanks). However, a pyramid on top of a prism is called "[elongated pyramid](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324182/what-is-the-name-of-this-octagonal-shape/324827#324827)". If we can apply similarity then this shape should be called "elongated cone".